# In Nexmo, how to pass parameter via NCCO input action

Tags: events, parameters, action, ivr, vonage

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am trying to make 'Route an Inbound Call' from https://developer.nexmo.com/tutorials/interactive-voice-response#receive-user-input-webhook.

So I knew that I can use 'input' as 'action' and route as 'eventUrl'.
https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice/ncco#input

For example, according to that page, I can use like this.

```
[
  {
    "action": "talk",
    "text": "Please enter a digit"
  },
  {
    "action": "input",
    "eventUrl": ["https://example.com/ivr"]
  }
]
```

Problem is from here.

I want to pass some parameter to that route - "https://example.com/ivr". such as from phone number as below.

```
[
  {
    "action": "talk",
    "text": "Please enter a digit"
  },
  {
    "action": "input",
    "eventUrl": ["https://example.com/ivr"],
    "from": $fromPhoneNumber,
  }
]
```

But it seems that there is no way to pass parameter to 'eventUrl'.

it says now there are only below things.

```
timeOut The result of the callee's activity is sent to the eventUrl webhook endpoint timeOut seconds after the last action. The default value is 3. No
maxDigits   The number of digits the user can press. The maximum value is 20.   No
submitOnHash    Set to true so the callee's activity is sent to your webhook endpoint at eventUrl after he or she presses #. If # is not pressed the result is submitted after timeOut seconds. The default value is false. That is, the result is sent to your webhook endpoint after timeOut seconds. No
eventUrl    Nexmo sends the digits pressed by the callee to this URL after timeOut pause in activity or when # is pressed.  No
eventMethod The HTTP method used to send event information to event_url The default value is POST.  No
```

How can I pass parameter via NCCO? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameters as part of the query string to the eventUrl.

Sam
Developer Advocate - Nexmo

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Sam Machin. But this 'input' action's route use 'POST'  method. Can you let me explain more detail with examples.

Comment: add: 'eventMethod' => 'GET', to the input ncco part, then add the params to your query string as @sam-machin said